# Dealing with a very high rate of duplicates

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Over the last few weeks at Bitcoin.SE, we have been having a flood of duplicate questions from brand-new users.  Not to go into details, but there is currently a global issue with Bitcoin that affects and confuses many inexperienced Bitcoin users, and so we get a lot of people asking the same question: "Why is my transaction not getting confirmed"?

We have a [canonical question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it) on the topic, with good answers, and we try to flag/close as duplicate.  However, we have a fairly small number of active moderators and 3K users, so it often takes many hours before someone gets around to flagging, and even longer before the question is actually closed.  In the meantime, these questions clutter the front page (at last check, 10 of the latest 20 active questions were effectively duplicates of this one), and often they attract duplicative or low-quality answers by other new users.

Are there things we can do better to improve our site's handling of this issue?  Or is this just an inherent feature of our low volume of active and experienced community members?

Answer (score 5):

For a specific outage the moderators could decide to place a system message (can't find an example now...) on top of the page linking to the question. That might prevent quite some duplicates already.

Another thing necessary is to have more moderators and active users with power. This is a common problem among a lot of small sites and it can only be fixed by an active community.

Comment: The system message is an interesting idea.  This isn't exactly a "specific outage", more a problem with insufficient design capacity, and it will probably be quite a while before it can be improved.  So I don't know if a system message would be suitable over that duration.

Comment: I don't think so then. Then fixing it as a community is the thing to do.

Comment: moderators can't place system messages anymore. They can still post featured meta posts to the community dashboard on the top right, but that is by far not as visible as the system messages were.

Comment: That is a pity. Only employees can now? @mad

Comment: @PatrickHofman To give you an idea of how long this will take to fix, people started proposing scaling solutions in 2013. "Just fix the underlying problem" is not a real satisfying answer in this circumstance.